# forum software with a simple RESTful API support

Tags: iphone, android, rest, forum

I'm searching for a forum software which offers  REST like API. It should be able to respond to simple calls like retrieve-post, add-new-post etc. and return the result set in JSON or XML format.

Those that immediately come to mind are phpBB, Vanilla, and/or vBulletin. But I don't know if they have REST API. Also I don't intend to deploy the forum for a website. I intend to integrate a forum like feature inside the Android and iPhone apps.

Edit: I don't intend to host the server on mobile. Just access it from the mobile app.

thanks

Comment: Out of curiosity - why would you put a forum 'server' in an iPhone app? (If I understand you correctly)

Comment: Do you really intend to deploy the server on the mobile device, or host it somewhere, but you only intend it to be accessed by a mobile app using the API you're seeking?

Comment: i don't want to deploy the server on the mobile.. i can host it on another machine, just be able to access it from mobile app.

Comment: ok. I found this framework called Elgg (http://elgg.org/about.php). It has RESTful API support. obviously it's lot more than just the REST api but will try my hand at it.